# cx_freeze fails while running setup.py on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, github-actions, cx-freeze

To create executables for different platforms for my application, I use GitHub Actions. The MacOS and Windows actions work properly, but it fails on Ubuntu for some reason. It says that it could not find a file even if it properly finds it on other platforms. I use tkinter with a tcl theme.

Link to my app's GitHub: https://github.com/sumeshir26/TimerX

Link to my cx_freeze setup script: https://github.com/sumeshir26/TimerX/blob/master/setup.py

Link to GitHub workflow file: https://github.com/sumeshir26/TimerX/blob/master/.github/workflows/release-ubuntu.yml

Failing Logs: https://github.com/sumeshir26/TimerX/runs/4530058102

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/TimerX/TimerX/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD/TimerX-0.0.0/setup.py", line 62, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 447, in setup
    setuptools.setup(**attrs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 291, in run
    freezer: Freezer = Freezer(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 1017, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.include_files: InternalIncludesList = process_path_specs(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/common.py", line 78, in process_path_specs
    raise ConfigError(f"cannot find file/directory named {source!s}")
cx_Freeze.exception.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named sun-valley.tcl
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MGhMc0 (%build)
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MGhMc0 (%build)


RPM build errors:
error: command '/usr/bin/rpmbuild' failed with exit code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

(Python 3.10)
If anyone could help, that would be really great.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO @sumeshir26. Please paste relevant code snippets along with the error message. Links and screenshots make it difficult for people with the same problem to find your question here :)

Comment: @rethab Sure, will add that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Python Error, after degrading to 3.8, it works.